# How to use gpg-agent to bulk sign git tags

Tags: git, gnupg, git-tag

My question is about the **gpg-agent** command which performs caching for gpg keys and pass-phrases.

I want to know how to use it so that I can run multiple **git tag -s** commands in a script without having to enter my gpg pass-phrase each time.

The initial version of my script is something like this:

> git branch -r | grep origin | grep pattern |while read BRANCH; do TAG=`basename $BRANCH`; git tag -s -m "tag $TAG release" "$TAG" "$BRANCH";  done;

I have two use-cases:

1. I have about 20 of release branches that I want to convert into tags.
2. I have about 40 release tags that I want to redo to follow a new naming convention.

I am looking for the command line for **gpg-agent** to run and then the gpg command I need to run to get my pass phrase cached so that it is useable when I do a **git tag -s**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by running `gpg-agent` before running the script. For example:

```
$ eval $( gpg-agent --daemon )
$ for branch in $( git branch -r | grep PATTERN ); do
>   tag="$( basename $BRANCH )"
>   git tag -sm "tag $tag release" "$tag" "$branch"
> done
```

You will be prompted for your password for the first sign (unless gpg-agent had already been used prior to the first sign). If using the above method, be sure to kill the agent after you are done (e.g. `pkill gpg-agent`).

More information on running the agent can be found here: http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html